# How understand OpenCV documentation

Tags: python, opencv, documentation

I'll start with an example. We see that in the C++ example, the function accepts different dynamic arrays. Just below is an example for python. The question arises, what should I use as arguments, list or tuple if I use python? Is there a difference in this, and how to understand it in the future? I am new to Python, and it can be very difficult to understand documentation, maybe there is a resource where the aspect of understanding documentation in python is discussed in detail?

[Example of Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T16zD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, it is generally best to use a NumPy array in OpenCV projects. A tuple is immutable, whereas a list is mutable, but most OpenCV methods work best with NumPy arrays. Here is a link to NumPy documentation: [link](https://numpy.org/doc/)

In addition, the OpenCV documentation is not very clear and sometimes is not entirely updated with respect to Python. I recommend using resources like [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io).

Comment: The python opencv documentation project is abandoned. The link won't work now. People have mentioned that there is python documentation as well as c++ documentation. It just feels less comfortable compared to other libraries.